# Grails Asset Pipeline - minifyJs=true, not minified

Tags: grails

I have this setting in build.gradle in my grails application:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
}
```

On startup all files are processed:

```
Processing File 438 of 741 - node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/index.js
...
Finished Precompiling Assets
```

No error is shown.

But the Javascript files are not minified.
I use this version:
com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2
and com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.2

What can be missing here?

Comment: Do you access the files with the asset tag?

Comment: http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html says it is grails { assets { minifyJs = true } }

Comment: are you accessing the js resources using the asset tags ? `<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>`

Comment: It might be that your assets needs to be under assets/ folder to work inside grails-app

Comment: which grails version you are using?

Comment: I use the asset:javascript tag, all js ar under the assets folder
Grails version 3.3.5